# Can't clip vector layer from a raster layer I created

Tags: qgis, clip, masking

I've been trying to clip an area in a raster image which I have created from an OSM. However when I fill out the raster clipping form I get the following message.

Error 1: Output dataset. tif exists,  but some command line options were provided indicating a new dataset  should be created. Please delete existing dataset and run again.

I don't really get this because assuming I'm making a new layer with only the clipped part, I AM going to make a new dataset right?

[image]

Comment: Try to use a different name for the output. Presumably this one already exists.

Comment: I have the same query and I have tried inserting overwrite in as it is mentioned, but I am still not able to get any output. I've tried changing the output file format but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the query by clicking on the edit button (button with the pencil on it in your screenshot - bottom right) and add the overwrite option to the gdalwarp command. That should stop the error about the existing file.
So your command would look like "gdalwarp -overwrite etc..."